# HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL

Tags: servlets

I am getting the subjected error, could you please help

servlet

```
public class FirstClass extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void doGet(HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException, ServletException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("this is a sample");
        out.flush();
    }

    public void doPost(HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException, ServletException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("this is a sample");
        out.flush();
    }
}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>hii</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>First</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>test.FirstClass</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>First</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/first.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="first.do">Click Me</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You've got the parameters the wrong way round - it should be the request first, then the response, like this:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws IOException, ServletException {
```

So currently you're not actually overriding the superclass method.

This is why the [`@Override`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Override.html) annotation is so important - it lets you find bugs like this at compile time. If you'd decorated your method with `@Override`, the compiler would have spotted that you were trying to override a method signature which didn't exist.

Comment: Yes... for example the call is doGet(Request,Response) on java Google AppEngine

Answer (score 0):

Does it also fail for POST?

shouldn't `<servlet-class>test.FirstClass` be `<servlet-class>FirstClass` instead ?

Comment: test is the package where class is defined

Comment: Hmm, that part should be ok. I also suspect the calling order Jon mentions.  If the calling order is wrong, POST won't work.